# how to troubleshoot on whether a file system had actually been unmounted or not.?

Tags: linux, filesystems, troubleshooting

We have a server on which, a couple of days before we got an alarm continuously everyday, that a file system has been unmounted.
But when we logged into the server the file system is still there mounted.

So the question is how to troubleshoot or find out if actually the file system was unmounted or not?

Comment: What program reported the unmounted state? What was the actual message?

Comment: "9/24/14 6:22 PM  Alarm: nuancelog@10.203.67.36 on 10.203.67.36 is Unmounted" was the actual message.

Comment: Don't you have paid support from nuance, they might now why their program behaves erratically

Comment: @Anthon: yes, but i also want to know for my knowledge how to troubleshoot this issue before getting to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the fact, I don't think there's any intrinsic way to find out about past mount and unmount operations. There may be indirect means, for example if the filesystem driver emits a log message.

If you want to tell whether a particular directory is a mount point at a given time (I assume that your filesystem is always mounted at the same location), you can look for it in [`/proc/mounts`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

```
</proc/mounts awk '$2 == "/expected/mount/point" {print "mounted"; found=1; exit}
                   END {if (!found) print "not mounted"; exit !found}'
```

You can put an [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) watch on a directory to detect when it is unmounted.

```
inotifywait /expected/mount/point -e umount
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it in a bash, if you want so.
`if ((mount | grep "/mount/point")>/dev/null) then echo "Is mounted"; fi;`

Comment: Replace `/mount/point` with your mount point and `echo "Is mounted"` with you handling code. Also you can add else, and run this script in loop.

Comment: For example:  `while (true); do if ((mount | grep "/mount/point")>/dev/null) then echo "Is mounted"; else echo "Is unmounted"; fi; sleep 5; done;`

Comment: could you please explain me the script.